How to Reduce PDF File Size While Maintaining Image Quality in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC
I'm creating a PDF book from scanned documents and need help optimizing the file size while preserving image quality. Here’s what I’ve tried and the issues I’m encountering:

Current Workflow:

ScanTailor Advanced (version 2019.8.16): Processing raw TIFF images with Color Operation options.
Adobe Acrobat Pro DC (64-bit): Merging processed TIFF images into a PDF.


Problem:

The resulting PDF file size is too large, exceeding 50MB.
Lowering the resolution to 100dpi reduces quality too much.
Adobe Acrobat Pro DC is very slow at merging images and doesn’t utilize multiple processor cores.



Specific Question:

How can I reduce the file size of a PDF in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC while maintaining good image quality?

Additional Details:

I need the images to retain their original color.
I am open to using Adobe Photoshop if it can help streamline the process.

Any technical advice or specific steps to achieve these goals would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Community This version focuses specifically on the problem of reducing PDF file size while maintaining quality.

thank you very much here is sample of images in a pdf  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xb5X6-GRH9_RmtFKmd9T4bkvqgjQVv-k/view?usp=sharing

@KJ  Thank you so much for your time and efffort to help me by the way  I tried to use Adobe Photoshop to reduce the size of each image by using Export => Save for Web (Legacy) with the JPEG Low setting but with no luck

@KJ The file that I sent you earlier was created from raw TIFF using software called DjVu Small to convert the raw TIFF to PDF. That's why the images are compressed, as you mentioned. Okay I will check the third file that you upload thank you again

@KJ, why not edit those comments into an answer, since it was helpful for the OP?

@kJ Yes, I agree with @ Drmoishe Pippik. Also, where can I find JP2 wavelet compression? I tried 'I Love PDF,' but it only offers low, medium, and high compression. There is no JP2 wavelet compression.

Unsure if this will help at all - have you considered converting the TIFF images to SVG? SVGs allow resizing and/or compressing with no quality loss (they're an XML text file for all intents and purposes) and TIFF files are usually quite large, with quality drastically decreasing upon decreasing the DPI (to provide an example of SVGs retaining image quality, see any of these PDFs where all CAD images therein are SVGs)

@KJ The CAD images in those PDFs where all SVGs that were tiny ~2" x 2" graphics on the site they came from [Honda's TechInfo], were imported into each PDF, and resized several times greater. Once I was done creating the PDF, it was printed to PDF using a high-quality Adobe profile to get the files compressed since they were hundreds of MB's prior to, which is why you're seeing what you're seeing. I probably should have linked to these SVGs instead

Because these images have a lot of text you can reduce file size and gain quality by using OCR to vectorize the text. I took your sample PDF which is 6,471 KB and did the following (I'm using 2010-vintage Acrobat Pro 9 on Windows so your menus may be different):

Choose Document>OCR Text Recognition.
Edit settings, set PDF Output Style to "ClearScan", set the Downsample Images to Lowest (600 dpi) to start, set the language to French in this case.
Click Ok to process the document then save it to a new name.

The resulting file is 2,328 KB. Hopefully you can get even better results since Acrobat has had 14 years to refine the process. If you zoom in a lot, say 800%, you may see some text is still pixelated, but most is converted to vectors. In some cases the remaining images that cannot be vectorized may have slight compression artifacts. In my version of Acrobat I can't see an option to control this compression.
The images in your sample PDF already appear to have compression artifacts. Check the output settings in ScanTailor and make sure it's not using lossy compression. It's best to start with a lossless or high-quality scan at a good resolution, say 300-600 dpi. If you still find compression artifacts in the PDF when you first assemble the TIFFs you can change the import settings as follows:

Edit>Preferences>Convert to PDF, choose the source image type (TIFF in this case), Edit Settings, then choose something that gives you good results.

